# shinyapp.io rename deploy path

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Need to change the shinyapp.io deployment path from
    https://username.shinyapps.io/abc
to
    https://username.shinyapps.io/xyz

Can anyone advice how this is done?

Comment: OK. Figured it out.

deployApp() deploys the app using the folder-name your app is created locally.

So, rename the folder of your app on your local machine from "abc" to "xyz". Test everything once & run the deployApp() again.

Comment: Now on shinyapps.io server the app is now deployed https://username.shinyapps.io/xyz.

Remember to "stop" the "abc" which could still be running on shinyapps.io server. Better still archive it.

As of now shinyapps.io server does not have facility to delete a service / folder. But the documentation says that delete folder facility will be available soon,

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

A key piece that I found missing from your answer is that you need to deleted the **rsconnect** folder.  The **dcf** file in this folder holds the name of the app and I couldn't get it to change by simply renaming my app folder.

BTW, you can now delete applications, but you need to archive them first as described [here in the June 24, 2015 blog post](https://blog.rstudio.org/category/shinyapps-io/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the following parameters; name, title, and url in the .dfc file directly.
This file is in the rsconnect/shinyapps.io folder.

When I republished the application it created a new .dfc file that reflected the edits and created a new application on the server.